# postgresql 12 function strange value / length behaviour

Tags: sqldatatypes, postgresql-12

I have a `char(13)` column named `a` in table `test`.

I created a classic before insert function with the following line :

```
raise notice 'a: -->%<-- len = %', new.a, length(new.a);
```

When I run `insert into test (a) values('1');`, I get the following output :

```
a: -->1            <-- len = 1
```

Strange, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not strange at all. `char` is a blank padded data type. So if you assign `'1'` to your column, it is actually stored as `'1            '`.

The solution is simple: [don't use char(n)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: actually the value is not assigned yet because we are in a BEFORE INSERT trigger function, is it ?

Comment: It is assigned to the field in the record to be inserted. Just don't use `char()` regardless of this problem.